# In the Demon Lord book series, are the main characters replaced?

Tags: demon-lord-series

Are additional main character/s added to T.C.Southwell's *Demon Lord* book series, or old ones replaced beyond the first book (e.g. as the series advances)?

**More specifically, does the main character have a child who goes on to continue the plot?**

Answer (score 2):

### No

The author's website (specifically the synopses for the various novels in the [Demon Lord Series](http://www.tcsouthwellbooks.com/demon_lord.htm)) indicates that Bane remains the key protagonist in **all ten of the books.** No mention is made of a son, or indeed any other major character who shares his adventures as the books progress.

> *The Demon Lord has travelled far across the God Realm to free the
> Fallen Goddess, and now he faces his greatest challenge. **The demon
> gods are a considerable nuisance on the voyage, and a new factor makes
> Bane even warier of pitfalls,** but no one foresees the danger that
> waits. In order to free Kayos’ granddaughter, Ashynaria, **Bane must
> avoid detection or risk a confrontation.** Without her co-operation,
> however, the plan will go horribly wrong.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Demon Lord IX - The Forgotten Lands](http://www.tcsouthwellbooks.com/the_forgotten_lands.htm)</sup></sub>

There seems to be nothing on the [author's blog](http://tcsouthwell.blogspot.co.uk/) that would indicate that he has any plans to replace this character as the series' protagonist in the future.